# Java Thread Dump Summarisation Tool

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace, thread-dump

I sometimes have to look at thread dumps from a Tomcat server. However, this is a very slow process as my application uses thread pools with a couple of hundred threads. Most of the thread dumps I look at include the same stack trace for many of the threads as they are idle waiting for work.

Are there any tools which would parse a thread dump and only show me the unique stack traces along with a count of the number of threads in each state? This would allow me to quickly ignore the tens or hundreds of threads which are waiting in a common location for work.

I have tried the [Thread Dump Analyzer](http://java.net/projects/tda/) but this doesn't do any summarisation of common stack traces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a tool to do what I wanted.

[Java Thread Dump Analysis Tool](http://mchr3k.github.com/javathreaddumpanalyser/)

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used it for a while but [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an online tool that does exactly what you ask for, no installation necessary:
http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/