# Online Java Thread dump analyzer

Tags: java, web-services, parsing, thread-dump

I often use Java Thread Dumps for post-mortems and server slowdown analysis. The problem is that the thread dumps are often long, and understanding the concurrency relationship between the threads might be tedious.

**Is there a (preferably online) tool that can parse a Java Thread Dump and show a humen-readable summary?**

Comment: Another SO user [seems to have written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417630/java-thread-dump-summarisation-tool) what you're looking for. Never used it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an online tool, no installation required:
http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/

I wrote it since I was also missing this.

Comment: Nice! Do you consider it a mature tool? Do you intend to add features to it?

Comment: It's definitely not mature since I just wrote it, but I have tested it on a bunch of thread dumps. Please report any issues. The TODO list is here: https://github.com/spotify/threaddump-analyzer#todo

Answer (score 2):

[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) (either Community Edition or Ultimate Edition) has a nice Stacktrace/Thread Dump analyzer.

It is not an online tool but you said *preferably online* so this is an adequate answer IMO.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks. Could you elaborate on its features?

Comment: @AdamMatan It seems that the Ultimate Edition (that I have) is capable of jumping directly to source to and also navigate up and down in the stack trace.

Comment: I have just tested the IntelliJ StackTrace Analyzer, it's very much equivalent to http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/ . https://fastthread.io/ seems to be a bit more advanced, but I haven't tested it yet. Anyway nothing can surpass Java Mission Control and Java Flight recorder, far more telling than a static thread dump.